# Adding dbfs in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, merge, dbf

I have built a model  in ArcGIS ModelBuilder for which the output is several dbfs having five columns. I want to merge all the output dbfs into a 'master' dbf sheet in the model itself.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'Merge' tool.

> Combines multiple input datasets into a single, new output dataset. This tool can combine point, line, or polygon feature classes **or tables**.

The Merge tool is under 'Data Management' -> 'General' -> 'Merge'

Comment: Or if the "Master sheet" already exists then use the Append tool.